# Excel VBA - Alternative to SendKeys

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to use AppActivate followed by SendKeys to copy an image from Excel to Microsoft Paint.
Although Paint is normally opened and activated, keystrokes sent via SendKeys do not achieve the purpose.
Is there an alternative (API function?) to use instead of SendKeys?

@phil-cohen
I made several attempts, all in vain; I tried hiding excel and resubmitting but to no avail

```
    ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Picture 2")).Select
Selection.Copy
Application.Visible = False
SendKeys "^V"
Shell Environ("windir") & "\system32\mspaint.exe", vbMaximizedFocus
Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:01"))
SendKeys "^V"
Application.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried reversing the order of your commands? Regarding SendKeys():
“This method places keystrokes in a key buffer. In some cases, you must call this method before you call the method that will use the keystrokes. For example, to send a password to a dialog box, you must call the SendKeys method before you display the dialog box.”
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.sendkeys